# How to reference local css files in a static webview window in android dev?

Tags: android, webview

I've created a static html page to be displayed in the WebView, I've a css file inside the `/assets/common.css` folder. The code looks like;

```
String linkCss = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/assets/common.css\" type=\"text/css\">";
String body = "<html><header>" + linkCss + "</header>" + content + "</body></html>";

webViewer.loadDataWithBaseURL("x-data://base", body , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Everything display correctly except the CSS isn't being applied. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
webViewer.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", body, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Using "file:///android_asset/" as the baseUrl is required to access files in the assets folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should also replace the `/assets/common.css` with `file:///android_asset/common.css` in the css link. Try this

```
String linkCss = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"file:///android_asset/common.css\" type=\"text/css\">";
```